# Confusion over cartesian product, how do elements in $\mathbb{N}^k$ look?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I was always under the impression for the cartesian product of $\mathbb{N}^k$, an element in the set was of the form $(a_1,a_2,a_3,...a_k)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct; an element of $\mathbb N^k$ is a $k$-uple of *natural* numbers.

Comment: As long as $k$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative definition of the product using functions. It is as follows: 
$$
\prod_{i \in I}X_i = \left\{ f: I \to \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i \ \ | \ \ f(i) \in X_i \ \ \forall i \in I \right\}.
$$
In your particular example $X_i = \Bbb{N}$ for every $I \in I =\{0 \leq i \leq k\}$. This definition becomes particularly useful if you are interested in infinite products.

**However**, you are right, it is merely a $k$-tuple of elements from $\Bbb{N}$.